# UPI - how to track all payments does by users to my bank account linked to UPI

Tags: node.js, upi

I want to capture all the transactions being made by users to an account number linked to my UPI account.

I would like to capture the amount, mobile number/VPA from which the payment was done and the date and time.

Am trying to find if NPCI shares any API for that

Please let me know if there is a solution